# Include admins in author drop-down on edit post screen

Tags: admin, author

In the back-end when editing a post there is a dropdown to select post author which is populated by registered usernames.

But, users with an admin role do not appear in the list, there is an "Admin" which appears top of the list.

That means the only way to assign a post to a particular user with role = admin is to go into phpMyAdmin and manually update the entry in the wp_post table.

Anyone know how to override the behaviour that removes admins from the dropdown?

[EDIT]

I inherited my theme files from someone else and now see that they had added a function in functions.php to manipulate the dropdown (I have CPTs which can be posted via forms on the front-end. All my users are subscribers, and so to be able to reassign posts in the back-end, that dropdown box is rebuilt to include users with role = subscriber. The admins hadn't been properly added back in.)

For the record, anyone looking to manipulate that dropdown for whatever reason, you can hook into the filter `wp_dropdown_users` )

[/EDIT]

Comment: I personally disagree, because all the users are showing up in my case (Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/38n72w), same is in Quick edit mode too.

Comment: I don't know what the roles are for your 2 users to be able to comment, but on my site all of the users appear in the author dropdown box except for 3 users who have role = admin who are replaced with a single 'Admin'. I cannot select one of the 3 admin users to assign them as author.

Comment: Thank you for mention the `wp_dropdown_users` hook. :)